# Raspberry Pi 4B script won't run without being plugged in to monitor

Tags: pi-4, boot, display

I have a Python Script which takes input from a USB camera to monitor the face. The script runs as expected and runs automatically on start up when connected to a monitor.

However, I need the script to run when the Pi is not connected to a monitor. The Pi boots up as expected, but the USB camera light never turns on, thus the script does not run when a monitor is not connected.

I have tried setting a default resolution with `sudo raspi-config > Display Options > Resolution` but when I click this, nothing happens and I'm taken back to the terminal.

I am running Raspbian Buster Desktop on the Pi 4.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

I needed to force HDMI output. I did this by opening:

`sudo nano /boot/config.txt`

and uncommenting the line:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```